# Prevent creation of extra files after tar extract

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I used `$ tar -cvjf filename.tar.bz2` to pack a folder and `$ tar xfj file.tar.bz2` to extract the folder and its files. After that, I noticed clones of the files in the format `._file1`, `._file2` ...

How can I prevent the  `._files` being created?

I'm using Mac OSX

Comment: did you untar the archive into the same location as the source files?

Comment: Are you sure you are on Linux?  Dot-underscore files are, AFAIK, MacOS specific.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--exclude="._*"` when you extract.

Comment: I found a much better way, but untested by myself: http://codeismandatory.com/?p=42